# DXA Delivery Solution HTTP Error 500

Tags: dxa

I am getting below error when I run the DXA delivery solution from my local machine.

**The localhost page isn’t working.
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

This solution was working/debugging fine few days ago. But now it is constantly giving the above error. It looks like the error is not related to any DXA (looks like VS or IIS Express or something else) but I just wanted to get response if someone faced this and resolved this.

when I hit the page, breakpoints in page view, entity view, layout is hitting. after the last line execution in the layout, getting the above error.

I am not getting any details in DXA log or Event Viewer.

**My environment details are below:**
VS-2013,
IIS Express 8.0 64 bit,
I have enabled “64” bit dll in VS-2013

Thanks
Jey

Comment: Does the port in your request (still) match with what's configured in VS / IIS Express ?

Comment: A 500 error like that would normally be logged as a warning from ASP.NET in the Application event log. Are you sure there aren't any?

Comment: @RickPannekoek: Yes, my VS port is properly configured in my dxa configuration file under the config folder. Also it is perfect in IIS Express applicationhost.config. I tried with reinstall the IIS Express as well.

Comment: @PeterKjaer: Yes Peter, even I tried clear all the logs from "Applications" under windows logs in event viewer. Then hit the solution, after getting the error, when I refresh the event viewer, I don't see any logs.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions occurring in the VS Output Window?

Comment: No Errors in Output window.       'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131287951779551391): Loaded 'C:\Users\U501869\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\02e0d727\b6ea8b81\App_Web_g2b31u4b.dll'. 
The thread 0x13b0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x3b6c has exited with code 259 (0x103).